# Magento 1.13.1.0 Full page cache files not generated

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I am  using Magento 1.13.1.0 and enable full page cache from admin.
It seems the page speed is good but there is no files generated under /var/full_page_cache.
I check the folder permission and its set to 777 , /var folder permission is also set to 777.
If I remove this folder, Magento recreates this folder automatically,  but no files are generated under this folder. Some of the folder is showing the usergroup as root:root while some of the folder shows apache:apache. full_page_cache folder is showing apache:apache as usergroup.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have memcached installed?

Comment: It would be helpful to add your app/etc/config.xml (without your passwords!) to your question, so we can make sure you don't have problems in your config.

Comment: memcached is not installed

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/p4pravin/folders/Default/media/28780b04-22d7-456d-b8cb-ba418d8e4410/local-xml.png @Tim , here is the screenshot for app/etc/local.xml and I did not make any changes to app/etc/config.xml.

Comment: Sorry, meant the local.xml indeed. Don't see any wrong things in your configuration regarding incorrect cache settings. There are many settings, but with this config it should just properly fall back to file.

Comment: Is this the only file in app/etc with .xml extension or is there perhaps an enterprise.xml also. If so, THAT's where the real FPC config is. If this really is all that you have, then you're missing the request_processor entry pointing to Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor.

Answer (score 1):

Verify ownership for magento/var folder: `chown -R apache:apache var`

My guess is that due to permissions, Magento will fallback on using a system temporary dir created with sys_get_temp_dir(). I saw this happening few times, on my machine it was using `private/var/tmp/magento/var/full_page_cache/`.